# Power of trajectory prediction Gold2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, prediction

I would like to add a force to my ball in my golf game, so if the player clicks the ball and holds a left mouse button, the power of the shot is growing, so is the trajectory. When the power reaches a maximum value the ball is shot immediately. I have a huge problem with it, and I'm stuck on it for a few days now. Maybe someone can help me? Code below:

```
 internal Rigidbody2D ballRB;
 internal Vector3 startPos = Vector3.zero;

 int dotCount;

 internal bool isClicked = false;
 bool trajectoryVisible = false;
 bool paraboleReachedEndOfScreen = true;

 GameObject trajectoryDots;
 GameObject ballClick;

 //TrajectoryDots
 List<Transform> dots = new List<Transform>();

 //shot velocity
 Vector2 shotForce = Vector2.zero;

 public float startValShootingPower = 3f;
 public float shootingPower = 3f;


 float minBallPointerDist = 0.5f;

 float dotSeparation = 10f;

 float dotShift = 5f;

 Transform lastDotTransform;

 void Start()
 {
     startPos = transform.position;
     startValShootingPower = shootingPower;

     ballRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
     trajectoryDots = GameObject.Find("Trajectory Dots");
     ballClick = transform.Find("Ball Click Area").gameObject;

     dotCount = trajectoryDots.transform.childCount;
     foreach (var dot in trajectoryDots.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
     {
         dots.Add(dot);
     }
     dots.Remove(trajectoryDots.transform);
 }

 void Update()
 {
     foreach (var dot in dots)
     {
         if (dot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled)
         {
             lastDotTransform = dot;
         }
     }
     paraboleReachedEndOfScreen = lastDotTransform.position.x <= -UsefulReferences.CameraViewFrustum.x / 2 || lastDotTransform.position.x >= UsefulReferences.CameraViewFrustum.x / 2;

     ballClick.SetActive(!isClicked);

     RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
     {
         if (hit.collider != null)
         {
             //check if the mouse is hovering ball click area
             if (hit.collider.transform.root.name == name)
             {
                 trajectoryVisible = true;
             }
         }
     }

     if ((Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1") || (paraboleReachedEndOfScreen && Input.GetButton("Fire1"))) && !isClicked && trajectoryVisible) //player released the mouse button or the parabole reached the end of the screen
     {
         trajectoryVisible = false;
         isClicked = true;
         UsefulReferences.ballScript.ballRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
         ballRB.velocity = shotForce;
         foreach (var dot in dots)
             dot.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
         Invoke("GroundCheckAfterShot", 0.1f);
     }

     if (trajectoryVisible && !isClicked)
     {
         shotForce = (transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)) * shootingPower;
         for (int i = 0; i < dotCount; i++) 
         {
             dots[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);

             dots[i].transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + shotForce.x * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (dotSeparation * i + dotShift),
                 transform.position.y + shotForce.y * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (dotSeparation * i + dotShift) - (-Physics2D.gravity.y / 2f * Time.fixedDeltaTime * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (dotSeparation * i + dotShift) * (dotSeparation * i + dotShift)));
         }
     }
     else
     {
         foreach (var dot in dots)
         {
             dot.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         }
     }
     //if the ball tried to fly out of the screen
     if (transform.position.y > UsefulReferences.CameraViewFrustum.y / 2 || transform.position.x > UsefulReferences.CameraViewFrustum.x / 2 || transform.position.x < -UsefulReferences.CameraViewFrustum.x / 2)
     {
         OnCollisionEnter2D(null);
     }


     if (isClicked && UsefulReferences.ballScript.ballRB.constraints == RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll)
     {
         UsefulReferences.gcsScript.gameOver = true;
     }
 }

 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
 {
     if (collision.tag == "Hole")
     {
         UsefulReferences.gcsScript.Score();
         ballRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;
     }
 }

 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
 {
     ballRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;
 }

 void GroundCheckAfterShot()
 {
     if (transform.position.y - startPos.y < 0.05f)
         ballRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;
 }
```

}

Comment: In your question you say: "I have a huge problem with it, and I'm stuck on it for a few days now. Maybe someone can help me?". Could you describe the problem you are having? What behavior is happening when you attempt to shoot the ball? Are there any error messages? How does this vary from the desired behavior?

Comment: nothing happens really, my ball doesn't change it's position